# Find value in vector and extract subvector from that position

Tags: c++, vector

I want to find a value in a vector and then create new vector, containing that value and all that comes after it.

For example: I have `vec = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}`, I want to find 30 and get subvector `{30, 40, 50}`.

I tried

```
vector<int> vec = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
it = find (vec.begin(), vec.end(), 30);
vector<int> newvec;
copy(it, vec.end, newvec);
```

or

```
copy(vec.begin()+it, vec.end(), newvec);
```

But it either show compiler error or the program crashes.

Comment: `copy(it, vec.end(), newvec.begin());`

Comment: it's vec.end() at copy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to copy to somewhere which is not allocated.

You can use a constructor of `std::vector` that takes two `InputIterator`s and creates copy of the range.

Try this:

```
vector<int> vec = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
it = find (vec.begin(), vec.end(), 30);
vector<int> newvec(it, vec.end());
```